# iOS SwiftUI - NavigationLinks cause app to hang

Tags: swift, swiftui-navigationlink

I am trying to write an app with recursively nested views. I am achieving recursion with a struct that has the names of it's "children".

```swift
struct IntervalData: Codable, Identifiable {
    var id: UUID = UUID()
    var name: String
    var intervalNames: [String] = [] // The list of children
}
```

I also have a class that wraps a dictionary with some cyclical dependency checks. This class is available as an environment object so that any level of the view hierarchy can access it to query for an IntervalData.

```
@MainActor
class IntervalDatabase: ObservableObject {
    @Published var intervals: [String: IntervalData] = [:]
    
    func put(name: String, interval: IntervalData) {
        intervals[name] = interval
    }

    func get(name: String) throws -> IntervalData {
        guard let interval = intervals[name] else { throw IntervalTimerError.IntervalTimerError }
        return interval
    }
```

I have the following view, and clicking any navigation link causes the CPU resources to be completely consumed.

```swift
struct IntervalDetailView: View {
    @Binding var intervalData: IntervalData
    @EnvironmentObject var intervalDB: IntervalDatabase
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List {
                Section("Interval Details") {
                    NavigationLink("Start timer", destination: TimerView(intervalData: intervalData, timer: IntervalTimer(intervalDB)))
                }
                if (intervalData.intervalNames.count > 0) {
                    Section("Intervals") {
                        ForEach(intervalData.intervalNames, id: \.self) { childName in
                            let childBinding = Binding(
                                get: { try! intervalDB.get(name: childName) },
                                set: { intervalDB.put(name: childName, interval: $0) }
                            )
                            NavigationLink(
                                destination: IntervalDetailView(intervalData: childBinding),
                                label: { IntervalCardView(intervalData: childBinding.wrappedValue) }
                            )
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle(intervalData.name)
        }
    }
}
```

I am new to SwiftUI, so I have the following questions:

1. What could be causing this problem?
2. How can I debug this problem in Xcode?
3. Am I doing the Binding initialization correctly?

Thanks for any help!

Some things I've tried/observed:

1. The preview window behaves as expected, this issue only appears when simulating the app
2. Replacing both NavigationLinks with no-state Text NavigationLinks does not cause the app to hang
3. Replacing just one of the NavigationLinks with a no-state Text NavigationLink causes the app to hang when clicking the Text NavigationLink